# Why does (1.3)(.7) != 1?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

This is the context:

```
1.3(10) = 13
13 - 10 = 3
|3| / 10 = 0.3 

0.7(10) = 7
7 - 10 = -3
|-3| / 10 = 0.3


(1.3)(0.7) != 1
```

If the difference between both real numbers is `0.3`, when multiplied together, why does the number `< 1` hold greater influence over the product (i.e. `1.3*0.7 = 0.91`) ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1934210/why-does-0-75-times-1-25-equal-0-93-and-not-1
Check this out.

Answer (score 2):

Here is $0.7 × 1.3$:

[image: 0.7 × 1.3]

And here it is again, with the green rectangle in a different place:

[image: 0.7 × 1.3 ≠ 1]

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$1.3\cdot 0.7=1\cdot 0.7+0.3\cdot 0.7$$ is the sum of $0.7$ and $0.3$ *of* $0.7$.  That is, when we "add back in" the $0.3$ by multiplying by $1.3$, we're adding only $0.3$ times $0.7$, not $0.3$ times the original $1$ we started with.

Alternatively, if you think of it as $$1.3\cdot 0.7=1.3\cdot 1-1.3\cdot 0.3,$$ we're subtracting $0.3$ times $1.3$, not $0.3$ times our original $1$.  So we're subtracting more than we originally added to get $1.3$ from $1$, and so we end up smaller than $1$.

Answer (score 0):

The two numbers you have stated simply have 1 as their mean. The same applies for this pair (1.1, 0.9) but the product of these yields 0.99 getting me closer to one. As the difference from 1 decreases, the closer I'll get to 1.

Multiplication is commutative and no number gets individual priority over another. I hope this clears your question?

A mathematical analysis of this would be -

In your example, the difference from 1 is 0.3.

You're carrying out (1.3)*(0.7)

= (1+0.3)*(1-0.3)

=(1)-(0.3)^2

Therefore your final product will ALWAYS be less than 1 unless your difference was an imaginary number.

Answer (score 0):

If I sell you a shirt that is on sale for $30\%$ off but then I charge you a tax of $30\%$, the two percents don't cancel each other out. This is because they are charged sequentially (not at the same time). The tax is applied **after** the discount, and so the extra amount that is added back to the discounted price is reduced since there is less of a price to tax.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you expect $1.3\times 0.7$ to be 1 because 1 times 1 is 1;  you removed 0.3 from one number and attached that to other, and expect the product to remain the same.

Let me generalise the question

That is, are the products $A\times B$ and $(A-x)\times (B+x)$ the same?
The second product is $AB+(A-B)x-x^2$. For this to be equal to $AB$, we should have $(A-B)x=x^2$ which is the same as requiring $A-B= x$ Or $A-x=B$ (and hence $B+x=A$). So that in the new product the original two terms are interchanged,; only in that case the product will remain the same.

Imagine a long procession of soldiers marching on road with 5 soldiers side by side and 100 in each line. This makes it 500 soldiers. Next day if the 6 soldiers go in each line it does not mean the lines will all be 99 long.